# How to disable resizing of textField in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout, textfield, layout-manager

I have a GUI, which is based on Swing's JPanelthat uses BorderLayout.In the north panel i have added a new JPanel which uses FlowLayout and contains two textField and other components.
When I change the text of textField and invisible some componets inside this panel, this textField keeps resizing. How can I avoid this? I would like the textField to keep the same size whatever happens. I've tried setSize, setPreferredSize, setMinimumSize with no success.

```
txtSource = new WebTextField(source);
    txtSource.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(30,20));
    txtSource.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
    txtSource.setEditable(false);
    txtDestination = new WebTextField(destination);
    txtDestination.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(30,20));
    txtDestination.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
```

**before:**
[image]

**after:**
[image]

Comment: using FlowLayout causes the component resizing. Try another layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492794/swing-component-disabling-resize-in-layout

Comment: the general rule is to _never_ use setXXSize (with XX = min/pref/max). Instead, use an appropriate LayoutManager. Assuming the WebTextField is a subclass of JTextField, you can set configure its prefSize in terms of "columns" (roughly number of characters)

Comment: Umm..  The screenshots?  Of what use were they?  For better help sooner, ***post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).***

Comment: @AndrewThompson they showed the resizing of textfields did they not? Is that valuable or not valuable?

Comment: @JohnnyCoder *"Is that valuable or not valuable?"*  Given that could have been conveyed in the words 'the text fields stretch sideways', not valuable (and a vast waste of bytes).

Comment: youve probably figured this out by now, but you could you a boxLayout with `BoxLayout.Y-AXIS` for your big panel, and in the top portion put in another panel with a null layout and use `setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)` and the texfields should not resize. Then add in another panel with the layout you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do this like what you want, some `LayoutManagers` ignore for `setXxxSize`, but you can use f.e. `BoxLayout` that accepts for `setXxxSize`

Comment: -1 LayoutManagers don't "accept" setXXSize - instead, they use the sizing hints (independ on whether those are incorrectly set by application code or correctly calculated internally) to size/positions components as documented (poorly ;-) by their api doc

Answer (score 7):

> When I change the text of textField and invisible some componets inside this panel, this textField keeps resizing.

This example shows text fields at a constant size.  Can you add an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of code that does not?

[image: Text Field Size]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class TextFieldSize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JTextField smallField = new JTextField(5);
                JTextField largeField = new JTextField(20);
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
                gui.add( smallField );
                gui.add( largeField );
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Text Field Size");
                f.add(gui);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//This works best for me:

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class NoResizeJTextField {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,300));  
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();  
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Text: "));
        JTextField tf = new JTextField(30);
        tf.setMaximumSize(tf.getPreferredSize());
        tf.setMinimumSize(tf.getPreferredSize());
        panel.add(tf);
        frame.add(panel);   
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {             
            public void run() {  
                frame.pack();  
                frame.setVisible(true);  
            }  
        });  
    }
}
```